# BCI research labs

Tags: brain-computer-interface, signal-processing, collaboration

I am fairly new to the community, so I hope I am going about it the right way. I am an undergraduate student from India with an interest in BCI research. Specifically, I am interested in researching mental disorders by utilising engineering resources, as I have majored in ECE.

I wanted to know how I can join research labs to gain more experience in the field of BCI. I eventually plan to join grad school, so I also wanted to how I can better prepare myself to make me a good candidate for BCI-related programs. Thanks!